Why snapshot field is located outside of testResults?
I have a custom jest runner that disables the tests in runtime. It means that if the test often fails among users, then it gains bad statistics and eventually begins to mutes (run and skip in runtime if failed) and then skips (do not run test and automatically create ticket). In some tests users use snapshot commands (for example toMatchImageSnapshot from https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-image-snapshot).
The problem is that the snapshot field in the test result structure is separate from the testResults field. It looks like this:
{
  // ...
  snapshot: {
    added: 0,
    fileDeleted: false,
    matched: 0,
    unchecked: 0,
    uncheckedKeys: [],
    unmatched: 1,
    updated: 0
  },
  testResults: [
    {
      ancestorTitles: [],
      duration: 103,
      failureDetails: [Array],
      failureMessages: [Array],
      fullName: 'compare images',
      invocations: 1,
      location: null,
      numPassingAsserts: 0,
      retryReasons: [],
      status: 'failed',
      title: 'compare images'
    },
    {
      ancestorTitles: [],
      duration: 100,
      failureDetails: [Array],
      failureMessages: [Array],
      fullName: 'some test',
      invocations: 1,
      location: null,
      numPassingAsserts: 0,
      retryReasons: [],
      status: 'failed',
      title: 'some test'
    }
  ],
}

I know that I should mute flaky test compare images but I don't know should I decrement snapshot.unmatched because it can be failed in another test some test.
So my question is: why snapshot field is located outside of testResults (type is here)?
Is there any workaround to this problem?
I expected that snapshot field must be inside each testResults.
